# UIAlertView not showing when other Views are being changed

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uialertview

What I want to happen, in order: Alert box pops up saying processing (no buttons), the main processing function is called, when that completes the Alert box disappears, and then my navigation controller moves to the next view in the series.

What actually happens: The window freezes while the app processes, then the Alert box shows and disappears instantly while the navigation controller changes to the next view.

Best suggestion on how to fix this?

Code:
    [_navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; //Camera dismisses
    UIAlertView *alert;

```
alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Analyzing\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
[alert show];

[self processImage];

[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
[self gotoResults];
```

Comment: use this one [self performSelector:@(processImage)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Analyzing\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
[alert show];
```

When calling `[alert show]`, the UI event is pushed into main run loop. You can process other tasks in another function. For example, a function named `foo` processes other tasks. And after calling `[alert show]`, we call `[self performSelector:@selector(foo) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1]` to invoke `foo`. That will give run loop some time to handle the showing event of alert view.

```
- (void)foo {
  UIAlert *alert = ... ///< come from above 
  [self processImage];

  [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
  [self gotoResults];
}
```

Edit:
   You can read about -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: in [this apple official document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003706). You can assign 0.0 as parameter for afterDelay, and the document said:

> `delay`
>
> ---
>
> The minimum time before which the message is sent. Specifying a
>   delay of 0 does not necessarily cause the selector to be performed
>   immediately. The selector is still queued on the thread’s run loop and
>   performed as soon as possible.

Comment: This seems like a great idea, but is it possible to not have the window show up in the 0.1 seconds? Like in some cases it may take longer for the UI to catch up? Or is this not the case?

Answer (score 1):

[self processImage] is running in main thread resulting in window freeze issue...
so you can use

```
[NSThread detachNewThread: .....]
```

for calling AlertView method